# Trying to post a formData using axios.post but getting `Unsupported Media type` error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to send a post request to a spring boot server via axios.post.
Here is my code snippet

```
export function createSingleProduct(productData) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const data = {
    catergoryName: productData[0].product.categoryName,
    productName: productData[0].product.productName,
    serialNumber: productData[0].product.serialNumber,
    purchasePrice: parseInt(productData[0].product.purchasePrice),
    purchaseDate: productData[0].product.purchaseDate,
    warrantyInYears: parseInt(productData[0].product.warrantyInYears),
    warrantyExpiryDate: productData[0].product.warrantyExpiryDate,
  };

  formData.append("product", data);
  formData.append("productPhoto", productData[0].productPhoto);

  const config = {
    headers: {
      apiKey: api_key,
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },

  };
  console.log(config.headers);

  return axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/products`, formData, config);
}
```

I have specified the content type but still I am getting the below error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "05-20-2023 01:27:36",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported",
    "path": "/product-crud/products"
}
```

The backend is okay. I have checked with Postman. Anyone can help me?

**Edit**

The postman documentation shows an example request like this:

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('product', '{\n    "categoryName": "Electronics",\n    "productName": "Desktop",\n    "serialNumber": "5007",\n    "purchasePrice": 45000.00,\n    "purchaseDate": "2023-05-16",\n    "warrantyInYears": 2,\n    "warrantyExpireDate": "2025-05-16"\n}', {contentType: 'application/json'});
data.append('productPhoto', fs.createReadStream('/C:/Users/NSL/Pictures/desk-pc-header.png'));

var config = {
  method: 'post',
maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: `${Base_URL}/product-crud/products`,
  headers: { 
    'apiKey': api_key, 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

**SOLUTION**

Had to use blob for the data. Updated Code is:

```
export function createSingleProduct(productData) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  const data = {
    categoryName: productData[0].product.categoryName,
    productName: productData[0].product.productName,
    serialNumber: productData[0].product.serialNumber,
    purchasePrice: parseFloat(productData[0].product.purchasePrice),
    purchaseDate: productData[0].product.purchaseDate,
    warrantyInYears: parseInt(productData[0].product.warrantyInYears),
    warrantyExpireDate: productData[0].product.warrantyExpiryDate,
  };

  formData.append(
    "product",
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
      type: "application/json",
    })
  );

  formData.append("productPhoto", productData[0].productPhoto);

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      apiKey: api_key,
    },
  };

  return axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/products`, formData, config);
}
```

Comment: Try passing `config` instead of `config.headers` it is expecting an object with a `headers` property. By putting `config.headers` you are just giving it the headers' object instead of an object with `headers` in it

Comment: Tried that too. Did not work. After trying several times I tried with ```config.headers``` Editing my post with only config.

Comment: Is productPhoto URL?? Or image data ?

Comment: productPhoto is a image data @Developer

Comment: @MushfikunnabiNijhum did you get it from input type file ?? Means did you get like input.files[0] ?

Comment: Yes from input type files like input.file[0] @Developer

Comment: @MushfikunnabiNijhum Send request without header. remove config from axios request

Comment: I need the apiKey in header. FYI, I tried removing content-type from headers. Found the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to append each key-value pair of your data object individually to formData:

```
for(let key in data){
  formData.append(key, data[key]);
}
```

Also can just pass the entire config object, change axios.post to:

```
return axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/products`, formData, config);
```

The whole code snippet:

```
export function createSingleProduct(productData) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  const data = {
    catergoryName: productData[0].product.categoryName,
    productName: productData[0].product.productName,
    serialNumber: productData[0].product.serialNumber,
    purchasePrice: parseInt(productData[0].product.purchasePrice),
    purchaseDate: productData[0].product.purchaseDate,
    warrantyInYears: parseInt(productData[0].product.warrantyInYears),
    warrantyExpiryDate: productData[0].product.warrantyExpiryDate,
  };

  for(let key in data){
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
  }

  formData.append("productPhoto", productData[0].productPhoto);

  const config = {
    headers: {
      apiKey: api_key,
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  };

  return axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/products`, formData, config);
}
```

Comment: I tried that too. It did not work.

Comment: For the first comment I want to say, the API is expecting the whole object as ```product``` to be a formData and the photo is another form data.